# Generating a default config SIMP file

Tags: rhel, rhel7

I am on a RHEL 7.7 instance that uses [SIMP](https://simp.readthedocs.io/en/master/).  I am trying to generate a default configuration (YAML) file.

Directly from [the SIMP docs](https://simp.readthedocs.io/en/master/user_guide/Initial_Server_Configuration.html):

> You can use the --dry-run option to step through the questions without changing anything and then run simp config  -a /root/.simp/simp_conf.yaml to apply the changes.

And further down:

> If you want to understand what variables apply to your setup, run simp config --dry-run and examine the generated simp_conf.yaml file. That file will contain both the settings and their documentation.

I've tried doing so via:

```
simp config --dry-run
simp config --dry-run -o default_simp_config.yaml
simp config --dry-run -f -o default_simp_config.yaml
```

**No file is generated as a result of any of these commands.**  What am I missing?

Info:

```
# simp version
5.1.0
# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug in the output of `simp config`.

When running `simp config --dry-run`, you should see something like the following header:

```
================================================================================
`simp config` will take you through preparing your infrastructure for bootstrap
based on a pre-defined SIMP scenario you select. These preparations include
optional and required general system setup and required Puppet configuration.
All changes will be logged to
               /root/.simp/simp_conf.log.20200128T140045

First, `simp config` will ensure you have a SIMP omni-environment in place.
Then, you will be prompted to enter setup information. Each prompt will be
prefaced by a detailed description of the information requested, along with the
OS value and/or recommended value for that item, if available.

At any time, you can exit `simp config` by entering <CTRL-C>. By default,
if you exit early, the configuration you entered will be saved to
               /root/.simp/.simp_conf.yaml

The next time you run `simp config`, you will be given the option to continue
where you left off or to start all over.
================================================================================
```

Note, that the save file is noted as `/root/.simp/.simp_conf.yaml` instead of `/root/.simp/.simp_conf.yaml` as specified in the referenced documentation.

This appears to be a bug where a leading dot `.` is being added to the output file in all cases and has been submitted as [SIMP-7533](https://simp-project.atlassian.net/browse/SIMP-7533)